# Why is my i2c failing to drive a usable signal?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

[I2C signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSEeD.jpg)

When I ping my slave device, I'm expecting to see its address written out (IIRC, it's 0100000) plus the R/W bit. Instead, I'm seeing basically nothing, other than this little blip. The problems I can see are as follows:

- The full address is not visible.
- The clock is only present briefly.
- The signal is very jagged.

This device is connected straight to the master device, i.e. the raspberry pi driving the whole board, and this is the only slave device currently populated. There is a 10k pullup on SCL and another 10k pullup on SDA.

Any thoughts on what could be the cause/solution of this issue?

- Depop'd the other slave devices to see if one of them was busted. I was expecting to see a change in our i2cdetect output, which I did, leading me to look at the signal on this line.
- Wrote the address to the I2C slave device. I expected to see the address on the o-scope, but saw the image above.

Comment: Try asking on electronics.stackexchange.com  This is off-topic here. However, to get that intermediate voltage it looks like you have made a potential divider, have you got one 10K pull up and another 10K in series with the master somehow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.